# WS7E mount partition as directory

Tags: windows-7-embedded

I need to mount a partition as a directory using Windows Standard 7 Embedded (WS7E).

Ordinarily, with Win7 (desktop) I use 'diskpart' to perform this task via CLI, or go through the disk management GUI menus.  However, these tools are not present (currently) and I cannot a component to add from the 'image config editor' in order to get this functionality.

If this is a totally obvious answer, and I'm clearly just stuck - feel free to recommend a good resource for getting up to speed in WS7E :)

Answer (score 0):

While diskpart is not available,  mountvol is.